# Rails 4 - cannot get ENV variables in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables

I am trying to get my ENV variables in production mode ...
but now way .. cannot reach the server ... the SECRET_KEY_BASE is not found ... if I hardcode it , then go trouble w the database creds, and if I hardcode them, got trouble w the SMTP creds...

this means that no ENV[] variables cannot be reached ...

I added the gemfile to get it in :production environment, and bundled it

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test, :staging, :production]
```

my .env file is present in my remote server  ( Ubuntu 14 - w .rbenv Ruby 2.0 , Rais 4.2 )

```
cat /var/www/workshop/shared/.env
   SECRET_KEY_BASE=106063d5146566142b6aa4782b874115c73a61ac2505f11f8e
   DATABASE_USER_NAME=myself
   DATABASE_PASSWORD=mydbpwd
   MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER=smtp.mailgun.org
   MAILGUN_SMTP_USER_NAME=postmaster@mydomain.com
   MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD=2fc998a7399999999a264b88c
   MAILGUN_SMTP_DOMAIN=mydomain.com
```

I set my secrets.yml file on the remote server

```
cat secrets.yml
  production:
     secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I set my database.yml

```
cat database.yml
    production:
     adapter: postgresql
     database: workshop
     encoding: unicode
     pool: 5
     username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER_NAME'] %>
     password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

and I updated my config/environments/production.rb w smtp creds

```
cat production.rb
        .....
        # SMTP settings for mailgun
          config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
            :port           => 587,
            :address        => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'],
            :user_name      => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_USER_NAME'],
            :password       => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
            :domain         => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_DOMAIN'],
            :authentication => :plain,
            :enable_starttls_auto => true
          }
          ...
```

Comment: Where are you running your production environment? Heroku? Usually the dotenv gem is a way to help development but not for production...

Comment: no I am running on DigitalOcean ... I read about .dotenv  in production , staging ... what is the best way to get my env running ... evven without .dotenv.. should I hard code values and upload them into the remote server ?

Comment: Do you link the .env to current folder?

Comment: Are you running unicorn? One way to specify the env vars is setting them in default unicorn file : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/unicorn-not-reading-environment-variables-correctly

Comment: no I link .env into shared..
yes , I run unciron...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I gave up w .dotenv in production...
I resolved using Rails 4.1 secrets.yml...

as I am deploying w capistrano 3 ,

```
- I use the gem capistrano-upload-config
- I created : secrets.production.yml , database.production.yml, configuration.production.yml
- I added in my capistrano deploy.rb
    set :config_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml config/application.yml}
    set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml config/application.yml}
```

capistrano uploads these productions files from the local .production files and link them... so

the server database.yml  is loaded/linked (from local  database.production.yml)

the server secrets.yml  is loaded/linked (from local  secrets.production.yml)

the server application.yml  is loaded/linked (from local  application.production.yml)

regarding the production.rb SMTP settings , I use the secrets file :
:address        => Rails.application.secrets.mailgun_smtp_server,
...

all these files are in .gitignore